# HP recovery error after moving the partition with gparted

Tags: windows-7, boot

I bought a Compaq laptop that come with HP recovery partition. I moved the HP recovery partition with `Gparted` from an Ubuntu live CD, and when I wanted to boot this partition from `grub2` option, I got a message like this:

> Windows failed to start. A recent
>   hardware or software change might be
>   the cause.
>
> - File: `\Windows\System32\winload.exe`
> - Status: `0xc000000e`
> - Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is
>     missing or corrupt

My Windows 7 is still found, I can also use Explorer to see the HP recovery partition (but I didn't find this path: `\Windows\System32\winload.exe`)

The partition was working just fine before this change. I don't have any HP factory disk.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery Partitions can not just be moved like that. You can repair windows the following way:

1. Delete all the partitions except your Windows-Partitions
2. Insert the WIndows-Boot-DVD (or USB) and boot from it
3. Select automatic repair

WIndows will now repair your Windows-Installation. Afterwards Windows will tell you to restart your computer. However, Windows will still not boot up. Repeat the Repair-Steps 2 more times. Afterwards your Windows should boot up fine.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, I know. I had the same problem with Windows 10. This worked for me:
https://woshub.com/windows-8-winload-efi-is-missing-or-damaged/
The same procedure can be used successfully for BIOS/MBR (my case). Here is what to do:

1. With gparted, copy the reserved (boot) partition and the Windows partition from source to destination disk (copy + paste into the unallocated disk space)
2. update-grub
3. Boot a USB pendrive with Windows installer (use Rufus to create the bootable device)
4. Click 'Repair your computer'
5. Enter 'Command prompt' and type "diskpart" + "bcdboot"[image]

Hope this can help others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).